# Prove $|iXe^{itX}|\le |X|$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, probability-theory, derivatives, characteristic-functions

Context is I'm trying to learn differentiating under the integral sign and characteristic functions of random variables with little knowledge of complex analysis (long story).

> Suppose $X$ is a random variable s.t. $E[|X|] < \infty$ and that $h(t,x)=ixe^{itx}$. Let $t \in [a,b] \subseteq \mathbb R$. Prove that
>
> $$|iXe^{itX}|\le |X|$$

Here is what I tried.

$$|iXe^{itX}| = |i| |X| |e^{itX}| = |X| |e^{itX}| = |X| |e^{itX}| = |X| |\cos(tX)+i\sin(tX)| = |X|\sqrt{\cos^2(tX)+\sin^2(tX)} = |X|$$

Is there any $=$ that is wrong and actually supposed to be $\le$?

Comment: if $X$ is real-valued, you have exact equality.

Comment: @Hayk thanks! happy sixth week of easter! ^-^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is exactly as you say, if $t$ and $X$ are real-valued. But if $X$  isn't, the inequality doesn't hold either: if $X=Y+iZ$, with $Y,Z$ real, then 
$$
|e^{itX}|=|e^{itY}\,e^{-tZ}|=e^{-tZ}. 
$$

Comment: Martin Argerami, thanks! happy sixth week of easter! ^-^